# Loading terms.html without the app

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a terms page like this

http://www.example.com/terms.html

but the angular app is always being loaded. I don't want the app to load only want to display the html page.

This works on localhost but doesn't work on the published site. The app is loaded and redirected to the www.example.com

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This will need to be configured on the server, if your terms.html is not a part of your current angular application and is not an separate angular application, this can be handled on the server you are using to serve files like express or nginx server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a request to http://www.example.com/terms.html is redirected to http://www.example.com, most likely the redirect was configured on your server. This technique is used with PathLocationStrategy (default in Angular) to ensure that if the user will enter a non-existing URL in the browser, the request will be redirected to index.html, which will load the Angular app and then the router will handle the configured URLs on the client.

The fact that the server treats terms.html as 404 could mean that your server is configured to redirect any url to index.html.

Try using HashLocationStrategy in your @NgModule and see if it helps:

```
  providers: [    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },...]
```